# covr shows 0% of coverage while all tests with testthat pass

Tags: r, unit-testing, code-coverage, testthat, covr

I have built a package with unit tests for most of the functions. The package has a standard structure:

```
package:
  - R/
    - file1.R
    - file2.R
    - ...
  - tests/
    - testthat/
      - tests_for_file1.R
      - tests_for_file2.R
      - ...
  - ...
```

Calling a function `devtools::check()` in R console gives me no errors

```
R CMD check results
0 errors | 1 warning  | 1 note
```

Calling a function `devtools::test()` is also successful

```
OK:       72
Failed:   0
Warnings: 0
Skipped:  0
```

However `covr::package_coverage()` give me this result

```
package Coverage: 0.00%
R/file1.R: 0.00%
R/file2.R: 0.00%
...
```

Why?

Comment: I have had something like this happen as well. Have you looked at the results from `covr::report()`? If so, was it any different?

Comment: Also, is your package source code publicly available, for example in a GitHub repo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem [here](https://github.com/r-lib/covr/issues/338)

I was missing `package/tests/testthat.R` file, which can be set up with `usethis::use_testthat()` and `usethis::use_test()`. It helped me.

Comment: I already have this file in place, but am still facing this issue. Did anyone else face this issue?

Comment: Thanks! I had my path as `package/tests/testthat/testthat.R` and it didn't work. Changing it to `package/tests/testthat.R`  worked.

Comment: In my case, I had some non-RData data in the `data` folder, so `devtools::check()` was giving an error. After putting them in the `inst` folder, `devtools::check()` went well, and the coverage changed when running `devtools::test_coverage_active_file()`